# git log shows (origin) without any branch

Tags: git, git-log

I have a git respository aligned to our (local) server; we are working with two branches (master and develop).

Lately, I noticed a strange report on the log:

```
47f7bf8 (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) <Commit message>
7c3e64a Merge branch 'develop' 
6a85e24  <Commit message>
794e28d  <Commit message>
6ad4058  <Commit message>
b73932c  <Commit message>
8527c54 (origin)  <Commit message>
ae68dba (tag: 20170213, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)  <Commit message>
66af625 Merge branch 'develop' 
4bfbc6c Merge branch 'develop'
```

If you notice, the commit **8527c54** is referring to **(origin)** without any detail on the branch it is...

The other branches I'm working on (master and develop) are actually aligned to the server, as I recently did a `push`

Strangely enough, I noticed that cloning (on my local PC) another copy of the same repository is working well, and I have no "missing" reference as in this case...

---

**Edit**: here is the output of `git branch -vv`, as asked in the comments:

```
* develop           47f7bf8 [origin/develop] <Commit message>
  master            ae68dba [origin/master] <Commit message>
  origin            8527c54 <Commit message>
```

Comment: What's the output of running `git branch -vv`?

Comment: @bejado: added the reply in the original question, too long to copy in the comment. Thanks

Comment: My guess is you somehow created a local branch named origin that is not tracking any remote branch. Remember, "origin" is an arbitrary name in Git, there's nothing inherently special about it. If you don't want this, you can delete it with `git branch -D origin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `origin` was returned from `git branch -vv`, it's just a normal branch that can be removed with `git branch -D origin`.

If it *hadn't* been returned by `git branch -vv`, you could use `git describe --all origin` to show you where the reference lives under `.git/refs`. In this case, that would be `heads/origin`.